# sql - find all jobs that do not need red parts

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a table 'job' that contains final products and a table 'part' that contains individual parts that final products are made of.
A third table 'supp_part_job' links jobs and parts together (since they are in a n:n relationship).
I want to **find all final products (='job') that do not contain red parts.**

**The relevant tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part` (
  `PARTNO` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PARTNAME` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLOR` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WEIGHT` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PARTNO`)
) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job` (
  `JOBNO` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `JOBNAME` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JOBNO`)
) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supp_part_job` (
  `SUPPNO` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PARTNO` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `JOBNO` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `QUANTITY` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SUPPNO`,`PARTNO`,`JOBNO`),
  KEY `SUPP_PART_JOB_JOB_FK1` (`JOBNO`),
  KEY `SUPP_PART_JOB_PART_FK1` (`PARTNO`)
)
```

How is this done and can this be done as a subquery as well as a join?

I have tried:

```
select distinct jobno 
 from supp_part_job 
 where partno in 
(select partno from part where color != 'red');
```

which does not work, since it - if I understand it correctly - returns all jobs that contain *any* part that is not red.

Comment: for me stackoverflow is not about "make my homework", sinse in your question there are no "keywords" by witch this question and answer can be found when other person have problem and find this question as solution for his problem i "vote down"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery below finds all jobs you don't want. The outer query finds the one you want.

```
select distinct jobno
from job 
where jobno not in (
  select jobno
  from supp_part_job pj
  join part p on p.partno = pj.partno
  where color = 'red'
)
```

Comment: I do not think this is correct, in fact I think "not in (color = 'red')" is equivalent to "in (color != 'red')".

Comment: Fixed accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice solution.